# How do I deal with emoji in Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

The hotspot I'm connected to has the SSID `12346`. I need to use the `netsh wlan show profile <SSID>` command, but cmd doesn't appear to have unicode support. What do I do?

[image: bleh]

Comment: Just use the new Windows Terminal.

Comment: @RichieBendall Obviously that wasn't an option when this question was asked, and still isn't and will continue not being one on several legacy systems.

Comment: Correct. I added the comment to give this question a better future prevalence.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I experimented quite a bit with emoji in cmd, and these are the conclusions that I came to:

1. In most cases, you can **substitute the emoji with `??`**.
   This is what the `netsh wlan show profile` (which lists all the network profiles) command shows me:
   [image: bleh2]
   In the above case, you can simple run the command `netsh wlan show profile 12346??`.
2. **But... CONFLICT!** What if there are *two* identical SSIDs, just with different emoji?
   To test this out I created a second hotspot with the SSID `12346`. CMD obviously couldn't differentiate.
   [image: bleh3]
   But the output of `netsh wlan show profile 12346??` had something interesting:

   ```
   Profile 12346?? on interface Wi-Fi: 
   ======================================================================= 

   Applied: All User Profile    

   Profile information 
   ------------------- 
       Version                : 1
       Type                   : Wireless LAN
       Name                   : 12346??

   Connectivity settings 
   --------------------- 
       Number of SSIDs        : 1
       SSID name              : "12346dY~?"


   [[REDACTED IRRELEVANT INFO]]


   Profile 12346?? on interface Wi-Fi: 
   ======================================================================= 

   Applied: All User Profile    

   Profile information 
   ------------------- 
       Version                : 1
       Type                   : Wireless LAN
       Name                   : 12346??

   Connectivity settings 
   --------------------- 
       Number of SSIDs        : 1
       SSID name              : "12346dY?·"
   ```

   First we notice that cmd (very smartly) runs the command for both SSIDs. *But we only want to run it for one SSID...*
   Secondly, we see that one has been assigned the SSID `12346dY~?`, and the other `12346dY?·`. However, using either of these in the command just gives us an error... *Bummer!*
3. **So what do we do??** Pretty simple, you use the Touch Keyboard (on Windows 10) to insert the emoji into the console, or you can copy-paste the emoji from elsewhere, both work perfectly, even though the emoji isn't displayed properly.
4. **What about Files and Folders?**
   I created two folders,  and . This is what `tree` shows:
   [image: bleh yet again]
   Luckily for us though, we can simply use <kbd>tab</kbd> to circle through the folder names at the prompt, but again, we have no way of actually viewing the folder names. In this case, one option is to rename the folders by using the `ren` command. Another option is to use the `dir` command to inspect the properties of the files/folders and determine which one you need.
5. **Just use ConEmu!**
   [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) apparently has better unicode support:
   [image: VICTORY!]

Comment: Interesting read (and source for the last image): [Abusing Emoji in Windows](https://davidzych.com/abusing-emoji-in-windows/)

Comment: The Windows 10 Creators Update appears to be pushing you to use powershell over `cmd`, is unicode supported there?

Comment: @Mokubai [Apparently not on anniversary update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b93kV.png)

Comment: UPDATE! [This screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So3v7.png) shows the command necessary to enable unicode in powershell. Thanks [@Bob](https://superuser.com/users/117590/bob)!

Comment: To [clarify further](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36606259#36606259), the screenshot in @Rahul2001's last comment is from the PowerShell ISE program (included with PS), not the basic console. The `chcp 65001` is meaningless, but there must be *some* kind of external command called first to force the ISE to allocate a console and allow `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to work; a plain `chcp` works too.