# Connect from cmd to WiFI with emoji in its name

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, cmd.exe, netsh

How can I connect to a WiFi network that its name contains emojis?

I tried the regular way of `netsh wlan connect name="name" ssid="ssid"`, and also with different encoding types. Tried also to copy the same text that I see when using `netsh wlan show all` (since I'm already connected to the network - through the Windows UI).

I'm also open to another command line solution that will work, as long as its a built-in one in Windows 10.

Comment: Related and probably duplicate but a couple years old so see if it still works with latest version of Windows: https://superuser.com/questions/1197986/how-do-i-deal-with-emoji-in-command-prompt

Comment: Allegedly - the new-future version of the windows console will do emoji  - so a precise build might be a useful thing to include in your question.

Comment: I haven't found this question on the search, thanks! Will look at it

Comment: In ConEmu it doesn't work for me, and I also tried changing the cp with `chcp 65001`